# Invocate correctly with EJB using JPA and Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jpa, netbeans, ejb

As a first step to start doing Spring work, Ive been tasked to do just the simplest of things. I've followed this [small little tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgXypqbjaDs) I found and copied it to have a starting point. But when I run the program, I get this error

```
Advertencia:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB UsersFacade, method: public void Session.UsersFacade.Save(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
Advertencia:   javax.ejb.EJBException
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface javax.validation.constraints.NotNull: @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull(message={javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}, groups=[], payload=[])
```

Even though I followed the tutorial correctly. Do I have to do more steps because I use Postgresql, or is there something else that I have to do that wasn't in the video?

Comment: You claim _"I followed the tutorial correctly"_, but you didn't. That tutorial is titled "Using JPA with Netbeans and MySql", yet you chose to use PostgreSQL instead of MySQL. Why?

Comment: @skomisa well, its because in the enviroment im working on we use Postgresql mainly. So its not because i dont want to use mysql, but because if i do ill just have to translate it to Postgresql anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the given error, it says

> Duplicate annotation for class: interface javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

So in the `Users` class I decided to comment the `@NotNull` and (after a second error) the `@Size` for all my strings. This lets me save things into my database without a problem.

To use the `@NotNull` and `@Size` correctly though, I had to modify the @Column to be like this:

```
@Column(name = "name", length = 20, nullable = false)
```

The only thing left is to limit the textboxes to the size of the columns.